# Closing server sent event in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, server-sent-events

My component is listening to firestore through server sent events

```
'use client';
import styles from './Messages.module.scss';
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import Message from '../Message/Message';
import { ChatContext } from '@/context/ChatContext';
import { useMessages } from '@/hooks/useMessages';
import { MessageData } from '@/typedef';

export default function Messages() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<MessageData>>([]);

  const { data: chatContextData } = useContext(ChatContext);
  const slug = chatContextData.chatId ? chatContextData.chatId : '';
  const encodedSlug = encodeURIComponent(slug);
  const { isLoading } = useMessages(chatContextData.chatId || '', Boolean(chatContextData.chatId));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!encodedSlug) {
      return;
    }
    const eventSource = new EventSource(`/api/messages?chatId=${encodedSlug}`);

    eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
      setMessages(message?.chats?.messages);
    };

    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, [encodedSlug]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.messages}>
      {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {messages?.map((message: MessageData) => (
        <Message message={message} key={message.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using swr to handle my api

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  return res.json();
};

export const useMessages = (slug: string, shouldFetch: boolean) => {
  const encodedSlug = encodeURIComponent(slug);
  const { data, isLoading, error, mutate } = useSWR(
    shouldFetch ? `/api/messages/?chatId=${encodedSlug}` : null,
    fetcher
  );

  return {
    data,
    isLoading,
    error,
    mutate
  };
};
```

Below is my api

```
import { database } from '@/utils/firebase';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const chatId = req.query.chatId;
    try {
      const chatRef = database.collection('chats').doc(chatId as string);
      const chatData = await chatRef.get();

      if (!chatData.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Chat not found' });
      }
      // send the initial data
      res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ chats: chatData.data() })}\n\n`);

      // listen to updates and send to the connected client
      let unsubscribe: () => void;
      const sendMessage = (chatData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData) => {
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify({ chats: chatData })}\n\n`);
      };
      unsubscribe = chatRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const chatData = doc.data() as FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData;
          sendMessage(chatData);
        }
      });

      // remove the listener when the client disconnects
      req.on('close', () => {
        unsubscribe();
      });

      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.end();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving Chat' });
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```

However, when I switch tabs or even close my laptop, I can see that a request to my api is being sent. It never stops. I even killed the dev server and the server sent events still seem to be going. It's been 10 minutes and I've sent around 1000 read requests to firestore.

[image]

How do I close my event source connection? Why is my firestore still being sent read requests? My application is not public so I have no idea where all these read requests are coming from.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have a similar issue. For some reason:
`req.on('close', () => { ... });`
is never fired

Comment: The only way I am able to workaround it is to have some interval that periodically checks `req.destroyed` flag but that kind of sucks

Comment: I was not able to resolve this, gave up and used polling to hit the api request every x seconds instead ) :

Comment: see this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52809

Comment: no idea why but res.on("close") is the one that works